# Calculating the sum of all odd array indexes

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I want to calculate the sum of all odd array indexes, but I'm having some trouble finding the right way to do it.

Here's my code so far:

```
    String id = "9506265088085";
    String[] strArray = id.split("");

    int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        if (i%2!=0)
        {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id.charAt(i)));

        }} 

        System.out.println(sum);
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working, or simpler ways to do it? To clarify I want to add all the numbers in the odd array index positions, so `intArray[1] + intArray[3] + intArray[5] + ...`.

**Edit:**
Forgot to mention I only want to add 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 and not 13.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Why not 13? Noting that there is no index 13, are you sure you know that Java (like most languages) begins indexing at 0?

Comment: The right answer is `33`. not `29`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edited your code:

```
String id = "9506265088085";
int[] intArray = new int[id.length()];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {

    if (i%2!=0)
    {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id.charAt(i));

    }} 

    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 7):

You are looping only from `i=0 to i=5`

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is right, you are only looping to 5. However, you're making this overly complicated; there's a neat trick you can use to avoid `Integer.parseInt()` and `String.valueOf()`:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < id.length(); i += 2) {
    sum += (id.charAt(i) - '0');
}
```

Also note that instead of checking `i%2` repeatedly, you can simply add `2` to the loop control variable at the end of each iteration (and let it start at `1` so you hit only the odd indices).

Comment: +1 I never knew that trick. Makes sense when I think about it.

Comment: This one is faster. (modulus operator is not fast)

Answer (score 3):

```
String id = "9506265088085";
int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < id.length(); i+=2) {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id.charAt(i)));
    } 

    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no Index 13 in this array as in Java index starts from 0. A solution to calculating the sum of all odd array indexes with Java 8 is:

```
    String id = "9506265088085";
    String[] strArray = id.split("");

    int sum = IntStream.range(0, strArray.length)
            .filter(idx -> idx % 2 == 1)
            .map(idx -> Integer.parseInt(strArray[idx]))
            .sum();

    System.out.println(sum);
```